# positioning a div in an iframe according to the position of a div in another iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, position

I have two iframes next to each other in a parent page.  I have a table in the first iframe and this table has links in each row.  When any of these links are clicked, the content of the second iframe is loaded accordingly.  However I want to display contents in the second iframe in the same vertical position with the link clicked in the first iframe.  For example, if a link on the top is clicked in the first frame, the contents in the second frame should be displayed on the top, or when a link on the bottom is clicked in the first frame, the contents in the second frame should be displayed on the bottom.  Is it possible to do that?  What would be the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

1. [jQuery offset method](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) to read link's position (in offset().top)
2. Send this value as parameter in link to 2nd iframe
3. use [jQuery css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to position content in 2nd iframe, depends on this parameter